# About Constrained permutation

Tags: permutations

In how many ways 'n' distinct objects can be distributed among 'm' group
where each group will get at most 'k' objects (it is possible that one can get no object)??
Thanks In Advance.
Example: (1)  n=3 m=3 k=1 
             ways=1  ,i.e (1,1,1)
          (2) n=3,m=4,k=1
              ways=4 ,i.e (1,1,1,0),(1,1,0,1),(1,0,1,1),(0,1,1,1)

Comment: Maybe you can show some calculations you have done?

Comment: Without the restriction of k objects it would be (n+m-1)!